# Is it "biased towards" or "biased against"?

Tags: word-choice

I've come across both phrases for quite some time and I can't seem to distinguish the difference between both of them.

Suzy is *biased towards* Thomas.

Suzy is *biased against* Thomas.

In both cases, it is clear that Suzy holds something against Thomas; but what is the difference between "biased towards" and "biased against"? Is it the degree of bias or is it that both are acceptable?

Comment: The premise of your question is flawed. There is no conflict. Either may be used, depending on context. The statistics were biased towards the mean value; the voters were biased against the party.

Comment: Sorry, but Suzy *is biased towards* is the opposite of "holds something against."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Suzy is biased against Thomas* can mean only that she has a prejudice against him. *Suzy is biased towards Thomas* is ambiguous. It can mean either that her attitude towards him is biased one way or another or that she is biased in favour of him.  For that reason, it is perhaps best avoided.

Comment: Supporting references, please, Barrie?

Comment: I've just found this addressed to a brand new contributor: 'Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.' – Community Bot. Even published academic John Lawler adds supporting references.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, answers can 'be improved with additional supporting information', when they are not plausible as they stand. This one is. Moreover, its having received 18 upvotes and no downvotes is 'supporting information'.

Comment: So we ignore the following advice from [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Biased-Towards-Biased-Against)? 'Biased Towards, Biased Against
 June 2021
Question
If I were to say "I am biased towards dogs," would that mean I either favor or am against dogs, or would it only conclude that I favor them? — Morgan, United States
Answer
To be biased towards something means you favor it over something else. To be biased against something means you do not favor it over something else. So to be biased towards dogs means that you favor dogs over something else, such as cats. ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, do I understand correctly that you think that the answer is wrong (on the ground that it conflicts with the source you quote)? If so, it would be more helpful, both to the author of the answer and to the future visitors to the page, to say so directly.

Comment: @jsw2 I'd say that not giving supporting references in a contentious area (and even professors of linguistics can disagree on issues) is unscholarly and against the spirit of the site. While I don't claim that 'Suzy is biased towards Thomas' is _unambiguous_, I'm saying that the standard of answers on ELU is lowered if such references are _not_ given, especially when counter-claims can be found in say Britannica (itself shown in the past to be not free from errors).

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think “biased towards” is ambiguous...
Understand the meaning of bias, just google the meaning, read both noun and verb (and carefully read google’s examples under noun and verb). From a metaphorical perspective, bias is a teeter-totter that has a push (which is against) and pull (which is toward). Simple example: I’m biased towards the color blue (I like the color blue); I’m biased against the color red (I dislike the color red).

Answer (score 1):

"Biased towards" means that there is bias, whether positive or negative, when considering a topic. This is typically used when having a positive bias towards a topic.
"Biased against" is always when there is a negative bias towards a topic. ie. There is a negative connotation attached to the word "against" due to its other uses.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of *biased* is akin to that of *inclined*, *leaning*, and *slanting*. That naturally leads one to interpret *biased towards* something as favouring it.

However, given that many people often encounter the word *bias* as standing for a bias that is based on some prejudices against someone (e.g. in discussions about racial bias), they tend to 'hear' it as akin to *hatred*, *hostility*, *aversion*, or *animosity*. Understanding the word that way, naturally leads one to interpret *biased towards* as interchangeable with *biased against*.

Although, invoking the etymology of the word, one could argue that the first interpretation is the correct one, the second one arises naturally enough from how the word is used that it cannot be dismissed as mistaken. The phrase *biased towards* is thus, for most ends and purposes, ambiguous, and precise writers will, therefore, avoid it. There is never any need for it, as unambiguous phrases *biased against* and *biased in favour of* are readily available.

(This is essentially the same answer as was posted long ago by Mr. England, but qualified to take into account an objection recently made to that answer by Mr. Ashworth.)

Comment: But the same flaw: no authoritative references. Answers lacking such come across as, and may be, no more than personal opinion. Kabilen throws in (and why not, if references don't matter 'I don’t think “biased towards” is ambiguous ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the answer offers a way of reconciling the fact that Mr. England's answer seems plausible to quite a few people (19 upvotes, no downvotes) with what appears in the source you quoted (and is arguably implied by some others). The answer may be convincing or unconvincing, but it is difficult to see how any 'authoritative references' would make it more convincing. If you believe that the answer is wrong, say so, and offer an argument against it; that would advance the discussion.

Comment: But two upvoted answers disagree with each other. And there is a wealth of recommendation on ELU that unsupported answers be avoided where possible; on the very rare occasion that I feel it right to give an answer but can only offer personal opinion, I stress this fact and am quite prepared to remove an answer shown to be incorrect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, every answer (and every objection to an answer) ought to be **supported by an argument**. An argument may or may not borrow from an argument that has already been published somewhere else. Whether an argument borrows from somebody else's argument is immaterial to how convincing it is. If one wishes to criticise an argument, one should make a counterargument, rather than merely point out that it was not borrowed.

Comment: '[T] his site especially prizes answers that have an identifiable basis in verifiable fact rather than just [(semi?-)localised observation]. Please consider strengthening your answer by citing some independent authority that draws the same general conclusion that you do with regard to this usage. Thanks!' –  Sven Yargs // 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.' –  tchrist

Answer (score 0):

People frequently say things like, "My husband is a wonderful guy, but I'm biased."
This is the same as saying, "I'm biased toward my husband." Anything 'biased toward' denotes in favor of. If it's ambiguous how you feel, you would more correctly say, "I have a bias as far as dogs." Then, you haven't stated yet if it's 'toward' dogs or 'against' dogs. To say I'm 'biased toward' something, if you wish to denote ambiguity, would be incorrect. 'Bias against' something, of course, is plainly just that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between 'biased towards' and 'biased against'.

Suzy is **biased towards** Thomas.= Suzy has a prejudice (unreasonable liking and trust) **for** (***in favour of*** ) Thomas.

Suzy is **biased against** Thomas.= Suzy has a prejudice (unreasonable dislike and distrust) **against** (***opposing***) Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, stumbled onto this discussion, but my two cents worth:

toward / towards is a preposition meaning 'with respect to'

Therefore, 'I am biased toward...' is not the same as 'I am biased in favor of...'

I am biased toward cacti, I don't think they make a good yard plant.

'nuff said.

Comment: What about "biased against"?

Comment: This would benefit from supporting information and clarification.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].

Answer (score -3):

A person who is influenced by a bias is biased. The expression is not “they’re bias,” but “they’re biased.” Also, many people say someone is “biased toward” something or someone when they mean biased against. To have a bias toward something is to be biased in its favor.

See at https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/bias-biased/

Comment: Who here said “they’re bias”? This answer is not saying anything that was not covered in the Q or its answers.

Answer (score -3):

As sometimes occurs in English, repeated misuses of a term -- whether carelessly or deliberately, but in any case, neglectfully and wrongly by the ill- or malinformed (a new prefixed, emerging term today, along with dis- and misinformed; -ation) -- tend to lead to "ambiguities" as in the minority, or, I believe, the less altogether sensible views of "bias toward". I attempt to make plain here that bias per se is a neutral tool that, possessed by either a promoter or an antagonist in relation to another person, idea, movement, etc, thus exercises a (now-held, no longer per-se) bias either toward or against the same linguistic object of the feeling in question. I thus discuss below bias per se and as an adopted noun; its special form as an adjective; and its regularly conjugated forms as a verb, along with some illustrative contexts.

This will be a little lengthy, but factual, and hopefully practical -- ie, literal and straightforward, without bias, if you will; ordinary, then, is a decent banner. I try my best to be accurate and wholly acceptable.

Bias, the noun, derives from a French, and ultimately a Greek form; its meaning is an incline, a leaning, a tendency; thus, its core reference and applied applications therefrom are both physical or psychological or both, and neutral: a bias can occur either way vis-a-vis its object: pro or con, TOWARD or AGAINST the same. Hence, on this literal, plain view of the noun, in and of itself, a sometimes-seen "bias toward," if "toward" there is understood in its plain sense, opposite of away from or, by inference, against, cannot by definition connote a biased against, or even a semantic "ambiguity," unclearly a bias that is either for or against -- at least insofar as a logic-based lexicography is concerned. So much for bias, the noun.

Now, if you're so influenced (read: driven) by, say, an idea, a force, a movement as to self- (or allow yourself to) suspend your (own) critical thinking about a subject or an object enough to wither lean in or away from a cult-mythology that has developed about the same -- say, the current disposition and frightful prejudice (the worst degree of bias; see below) against those who, for any personal reason or another, chose not to receive the so-called COVID-19 vaccine and its boosters -- welcome, then, to being properly labeled as, at least BIASED -- in the least offensive, antisocial sense. It is indeed a passive, hapless, and unenviable psychosocial state, insofar as intellectual honesty is concerned, if such honesty still counts as a virtue.

To be irreversibly cemented to or biased about -- so, for or against -- a certain phenomenon in nature, including the world and in its myriad parts, paths, and participants, human or otherwise, is not prized among the harder working, earnestly thinking crowd. It used to be shameful to be biased.

Take, eg, the case of the UN's perennial bias against Israel's management of and treatment toward Palestinians living in its disputed territories. The UN disposition toward and discrimination against Israel, a viciously and falsely labeled "apartheid state," is constant and unrelenting. See, eg, https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/world/israel-citing-bias-won-t-cooperate-with-un-rights-team/ar-AAU05kP?ocid=msedgntp; and, for more basic history, https://www.factsaboutisrael.uk/israeli-palestinian-conflict-summary/

So, better, they say, to go with the facts, the science, the reliable and least impeachable truth; but, if only we were hard-wired, rather, to ignore our irrational, ruling feelings, passions and needs. So, then, so much the easier said to be unbiased -- to live in a utopian social vacuum -- than to be human, social, and sometimes, if only too tragically, biased, to further illustrate the fuller case with the term.

It is thus natural to find individual, community, or institutional bias in human society; however, it is relatively enlightened, exemplary, and praiseworthy for one to recognize and admit one's or a collective's bias in any open, constructive, and intellectually bona-fide discussions and analyses.

Finally, bias, the verb, adapts in its action to the configuration of the noun characterized above. So, eg, "He biases (is biasing; was, had been biased, etc) his conclusion -- notwithstanding, his fair and sensible premises adduced earlier -- carelessly, even recklessly without due and proper concern for the community's opinion of his own reputation as a serious scholar."

To reiterate, a bias per se is capable of being leaned either toward or against someone or something. Still, it must be possessed and internalized by its holder/operator to reflect sich individual user's bias toward -- pro -- something or someone, or against -- con -- the same thing or person. One may be described as biased (the least malicious station on the road to the more and most serious judgment-impaired destinations of jaundiced and prejudiced or bigoted, respectively); and it is, by popular convention, a psychosocial affliction, from not good to awful and terribly despised.

And lastly, for one to bias, ie, illogically or otherwise wrongly determine an outcome, whether intentionally or otherwise, is not, it is generally maintained, to do justice toward the outcome-event, following its fairly devised and involved structures and processes, whatever their nature.

I welcome any questions or comments to better the understanding of the present term's per-se and qualified forms as noun, as a modified adjective, and as its conjugated verb-forms in regular, American speech and writing.
Above all else, try not to read the above too personally, as to feel targeted and hurt. My views, like yours, were you writing here, are irrelevant to any correctly researched and stated knowledge conveyed in the text's central material. Stay within the rails and you'll ride, ie, read and learn much better. Yet, if and where I err materially, please let me know, so I can, by reading your corrective and thus better account, revise mine here. The goal is commonly improved knowledge and practice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your comment, although welcome, is hard to plumb; it's vague and mysterious as to where I need supportive documentation.  (Anyway, I've added some, in a show of good faith.)My contribution's account is descriptive in nature and not a persuasive argument, where documentation, in order to be believed and adopted by the reader, is essential. Mine is logic-and-fact based and thus stands on its inherent, deductive merits, rather than any inductive ones, by contrast.